# Next.js unable to deploy in Azure. Error The size of the function content was too large

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-static-web-app

Unable to deploy the Next.js SSR app in Azure static-web-app. i added the required configurations in yml file to restrict the cache but still getting ERROR: *"The size of the function content was too large. The limit for this Static Web App is 104857600 bytes"*

yml file:
[image]

Pakage.json file:
[image: Pakage.json file:]

Error:
[image: Error]

As per [latest update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nextjs-hybrid#enable-standalone-feature) i also tried to put `module.exports ={ output:"standalone", }` in the next.config.js file but still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

My next.config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = async (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  /**
   * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
   */
  const nextConfig = {
    output: 'standalone',
  };

  return nextConfig;
};
```

And it has correctly reduced my bundle size. I only share this as maybe it needs to be exported as a function?